# ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '0.9'

Tags: angular, pipe

I am working on an Ionic app . My app is get data json api earthquake form USGS. l used pipe to change color of background style for value magnitude earthquake .

```
export class MagsCssPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    let mags = value

    if (value >Math.floor(0.0) && value <= 0.9) {
  return "one"
} else if (value >Math.floor(1) && value <= 1.9) {
  return "one"
} else if (value >Math.floor(2) && value <= 2.9) {
  return "tow"
} else if (value > Math.floor(3) && value <= 3.9) {
  return "there"
} else if (value > Math.floor(4) && value <= 4.9) {
  return "four"
} else if (value > Math.floor(5) && value <= 5.9) {
  return "fife"
} else if (value > Math.floor(6) && value <= 6.9) {
  return "six"
} else if (value > Math.floor(7) && value <= 7.9) {
  return "seven"
} else if (value > Math.floor(8) && value <= 8.9) {
  return "eight"
} else if (value > Math.floor(9) && value <= 9.9) {
  return "ninue"
}

    return mags


  }

}
```

but when l run my app l get

```
 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '0.9'
```

html

```
 <span [ngClass]='item.properties.mag | magsCss'>{{item.properties.mag}}</span>&#160;&#160;
        <span> {{item.properties.place}}</span>
```

console log

[image]

Comment: Try to use `Math.floor()` to transform 0.9 to 0, 1.9 to 1 etc.

Comment: any example please ?

Comment: Please do a `consonle.log(mags)` right after variable assignment and post it here. It looks like you are not passing a number but other type

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Comment: l get value in console and he is working fine !

Comment: Please post a screenshot of this console.log. Also you could run `console.log(typeof mags)`. If it's not a `number` then you have to transform the value to a number.

Comment: `value < 0.9` is not inclusive. Did you mean `value <= 0.9`?

Comment: @Sergey i updated my question

Comment: @Clint l didnt used = in my code ! :-/

Comment: Provide a minimal reproduction of your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see you have a problem when you get exactly `0.9` because your statements don't consider it.

If you need to include `0.9` in comparison you have to use `x <= 0.9` what means less or equal.

If you are good with having `0` where it is `0.99` you can use next strategy

```
export class MagsCssPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    let mags = Math.floor(+value)

    switch(mags) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            return "one"
        case 2:
            return "tow"
        case 3:
            return "there"
        case 4:
            return "four"
        case 5:
            return "fife"
        case 6:
            return "six"
        case 7:
            return "seven"
        case 8:
            return "eight"
        case 9:
            return "ninue"
        default:
            return "";
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer . l got ERROR `Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '1.72'` , so in that case l have to use `x <= 0.9`

Comment: Did you mean to add a `Math.floor` in there somewhere?

Comment: i didn't used Math.floor @JohnMontgomery

Comment: Fixed my answer

Comment: some value is working fine but with others i got `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '-1'`

Comment: How is it possible that the value is negative? What should happen to the Earth in this case :)

Comment: @AliGhassan If it's possible to get invalid values, you should probably designate a class for that (or default it to one of the others) rather than returning the original value.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery how ? l am beginner

Comment: @AliGhassan I've updated my answer to ignore the values that do not go under conditions to prevent from errors. The only problem I can see is that CSS doesn't work with numbers and Angular catches this before the assignment.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery what is the sake of making a class? It just needs either condition or filter.

Comment: @Sergey Well, since it's being passed to `ngClass` I assume there's some styling involved, and he might want to identify invalid results in some way. But passing back an empty string works just as well if that isn't needed.

Comment: after you updated you answer now he is  ignore the values that do not go under conditions https://i.imgur.com/rqBNSOm.jpg check my app

Comment: @AliGhassan if you want to color all "invalid" results in some way just replace `""` with any *string* you want and define a class for it in CSS.